# Dual Consent Laws of California Relating To Residents Of Other State's

Tags: privacy, california

CA Penal Code 632 sets forth that all parties must be notified that a conversation is to be recorded.

I have a person whom I'd like to assist in a proceeding, possibly, given the situation is correct.

I live in a different state, Texas, which is not a dual consent state.

Am I correct in thinking that I can record a phone call with a California resident, while I'm located in Texas? The product of which would eventually be used in a California court if all goes well.

EDIT for better context:

1 - The phone call would be made from Texas, by a Texas resident;

2 - The phone call would be made to the wife of a family member (who both live and are married in California);

3 - The recording would be given to the husband's attorney, who would then try the divorce/custody case in the State of California with the recording as evidence (if admissible, granted I'm not stepping on any laws)

I'm not concerned that I'd get in trouble as a Texas resident. I'm concerned about admissibility in California Family Courts.

Answer (score 2):

No.

If you are in Texas and they are in California then you must comply with both state’s laws.  The collection is illegal under California law and illegally collected evidence is inadmissible.

Comment: Would it be legal to inform the callee that he is in Texas and that they agree to abide by Texas’s laws?

Comment: @Victor you can't agree with someone that certain laws don't apply (unless the law says you can). You can agree for example, that Texas law will apply to a contract but that is only for the interpretation of that contract - any obligations you have under Californian, Pakistani or Uzbek law still apply.

Comment: I'd be interested to see how this relates to situations where you do not know where the other person is located - eg a caller with a withheld number.

Comment: That isn't true. He only has to comply with Texas law while in Texas.

Comment: He has to comply with California law while calling California. See Kearney v. Salomon Smith Barney, Inc.

Comment: @Moo you would have to assume that you can’t unless you can verify their location. The onus is always on you to comply with the law.

Comment: @Putvi can you provide links to your comment and answer the question?

Comment: @Ja-oonSolo there isn't just one law to link to to say CA can't force it's laws upon a Texas resident, but just by virtue of the 14th amendment and every state being allowed to form it's own laws, you only have to follow Texas law while in Texas.

Comment: I edited for better context.

Comment: @Putvi - In Kearney v. Salomon Smith Barney, Inc the CA supreme court agreed that it could not fine someone in Georgia for violating the CA 2-party recording rule but it did allow an injunction on the George based company to stop doing it.

Comment: Good job looking it up @GeorgeWhite

Comment: user6726 cited it, I just read it.